# In three dimensions, the Laplacian of $1/r$ is $0$ outside the origin

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian

Why does the following hold?

$$\Delta_{3}\frac{1}{r}\Bigg\vert_{\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace}=0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: $\Delta 1/|x| = -4\pi\delta(0)$.

$$
\begin{align}
I(x) = \int\limits_D \Delta_x \frac{1}{|x - x'|} dx'
&= \int\limits_D \mbox{div}_x\,\mbox{grad}_x \frac{1}{|x-x'|} dx'
= - \int\limits_D \mbox{div}_x\frac{x-x'}{|x-x'|^3} dx' \\
&= - \int\limits_{\partial D}\frac{1}{|x-x'|^2} e_r \cdot dA'
\end{align}
$$
where I used 
$$
\left(\mbox{grad}_x \frac{1}{|x|} \right)_i =
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{1}{|x|} = 
\partial_i \left(\sum_j x_j^2\right)^{-1/2} =
-\frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_j x_j^2\right)^{-3/2} 2 x_i=
-\frac{x_i}{|x|^3}
$$

For $x = 0$ for $D$ being a ball of radius $R$ without inner ball of radius $\epsilon$ one gets
$$
I(0) = -4\pi \left(\frac{R^2}{R^2}- 
\frac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon^2}\right) = 0
$$

The limit $R\to\infty$ doesn't change the result.

The surface area of the ball is proportional to $R^2$ while it gets compensated by the constant $1/R^2$ term.

This is also consistent with the Gauss theorem of electrostatics, as there is no point source included in $D$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use the expression for the Laplacian in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Note that $r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\frac1r$ is a constant...

Comment: When you apply the second $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ to that constant, you get $0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: You get nothing because the function is not defined at $r=0$ (and has a singularity there). To obtain a correct answer everywhere you should differentiate in the sense of distributions $\langle \Delta(\frac1r),\phi\rangle=\langle (\frac1r),\Delta\phi\rangle$ for any smooth compactly supported function $\phi$, then cut away a small ball with center the origin and integrate by parts using Green's formula.

Comment: Yes, of course. I just did not wish to make all the computations myself :)